# Omit tracking info from git status output

Tags: git, status

I only want to know if a rebase, merge or cherry-pick command is going on or not. git status output gives me that info, but when there are too many files that is staged or changed, the interesting bits of the output is lost at the top of my command window which is inconvenient to deal with.
I couldn't find an option of git status that would allow me to omit the changes and only show the general status of the working tree. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: `git status | sed '/^$/Q'`?

Answer (score 0):

As implied by the comment, you can pipe your `git status` to another command and format it.  This answer has some other options as well as details about what you are looking to do:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578537/awk-starting-from-a-fixed-text-until-the-first-blank-line

Basically, you want to print the output from `git status` until you come to a new line.  So using `git status | sed -e '/^$/q'`, would work.
This takes the output from git and passes it through looking to see if you are on a new line (where the start and end of the line have nothing between them) and then stops.

Alternatively, you could just use `head -x` to see the first however many lines of the `git status`.  `git status | head -2` would show you only the first two lines and for me would show that I am rebasing.